# How can i config git/github version control on magento project in Phpstorm?

Tags: git, magento, github, version-control, phpstorm

I am using phpstorm in magento development, and we have different developers keep working on this project, although the local history do help a lot, it is not easily to keep track the new changes among our development work.

Is there any good guidelines to teach how to config git or github properly in phpstorm?

Thanks!

Comment: **1)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/10/webinar-recording-version-control-with-phpstorm-and-other-intellij-idea-based-ides/ **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/?s=vcs

Comment: What's the specific challenge that you're facing?

Comment: PhpStorm comes packaged with VCS Integration. See @LazyOne's links